# Given a SQL query, can we find django code that generated it?

Tags: mysql, django-models

Given a SQL query, can we find django code that generated it? (reverse engineering database query to django code
e.g. opposite/reverse of following operation)

```
q = Item.objects.all()
print(q.query)`

Input = db query = 
"SELECT * FROM table.Item"

Output = django code = 
Item.objects.all()
```

Comment: I doubt it, because the reverse transformation is not unique.  What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Programmatically absolutely not as mysql is not aware (nor cares) about the application code it generated the sql code. Manually you can guess based on table names and other parts of the sql statement.

Comment: Yoy could probably write a python code that parses an sql statement and using django models generates an orm code out of it, but this is going to be a very complex stuff to do.

Comment: I wish to know what django code created following MySQL query, 

SELECT `id`, column1, column2, column3  FROM table_schema.table_name WHERE  (NOT ((`id` <= 97000000) ))  AND  ( (`id` <= 97500000) )

very weird looking Where clause there...